# How do display a key value from this string?

Tags: php, json

This is my JSON data

```
{"subtotal":{"amount":"403.95","currency":"USD"},"fees":[{"coinbase":{"amount":"4.04","currency":"USD"}},{"bank":{"amount":"0.15","currency":"USD"}}],"total":{"amount":"408.14","currency":"USD"},"amount":"408.14","currency":"USD"}
```

I just need to display the "amount" key and am attempting to parse json.. Am I going about this correctly?

Comment: You given the json array. What you have tried to get the value using php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this

```
<?php
$str='{"subtotal":{"amount":"403.95","currency":"USD"},"fees":[{"coinbase":{"amount":"4.04","currency":"USD"}},{"bank":{"amount":"0.15","currency":"USD"}}],"total":{"amount":"408.14","currency":"USD"},"amount":"408.14","currency":"USD"}';
$arr=json_decode($str,true);

echo $arr['subtotal']['amount'];
```

Comment: Thank you. Im getting my string from var_dump

$str='echo $scraped_coin';
$arr=json_decode($str,true);

echo $arr['subtotal']['amount']; aand its not working?

Comment: Ive answered my own question

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$jsondata = '{"subtotal":{"amount":"403.95","currency":"USD"},"fees":[{"coinbase":{"amount":"4.04","currency":"USD"}},{"bank":{"amount":"0.15","currency":"USD"}}],"total":{"amount":"408.14","currency":"USD"},"amount":"408.14","currency":"USD"}';$jsondata1 = json_decode($jsondata);echo $jsondata1->amount;echo $jsondata1->subtotal->amount;
```